# What is the opposite of CLICK event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had a list `<li>` where the content inside li should get bold when it is clicked. For that i used the following code

**HTML**

```
  <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1" style="padding-left:5px;">All Sectors</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Information Technology</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Manufacturing</a></li>
        <li style="border-right:none;"><a href="#tab4">Services</a></li>        
  </ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs li a").click(
        function() { $(this).css({ "font-weight" : "bold" }); }     

    );

});
```

But When the list item is clicked it gets bold. I want the **list item to get back to normal when the other list item is clicked**. I am not able to find the correct event. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no event for that. You will have to store which element was made bold last time (e.g. `lastClicked = this`), and set that to normal again (`lastClicked.css(....)`).

Comment: What kind of event were you expecting here? The "we read your mind and figured you wanted us to fire an event on all these items when you clicked on that other item" event?

Comment: @ceejayoz - I think he was looking for something akin to `focus`/`blur` events, it's not an unreasonable question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It would actually be easier to do this at the `<li>` level rather than the `<a>` since it would have the same bolding effect (and direct access to [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)), like this:

```
$(".tabs li").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("boldClass").siblings().removeClass("boldClass");
});
```

Then you can use CSS for the class like this:

```
.boldClass { font-weight: bold; }
```

Instead of [`.addClass("boldClass")`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) you could use [`.toggleClass("boldClass")`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) if you want a click on an already-bold link to un-bold it.

Comment: I like this solution a lot! Simple and clean... I really need to play with idiomatic jQuery more :-)

Answer (score 9):

Maybe set the other items to normal before setting the clicked item to bold? I'm not the greatest with jQuery so this code my be utter crap :-)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs li a").click(
        function() { 
           $(".tabs li a").css({ "font-weight" : "normal" }); 
           $(this).css({ "font-weight" : "bold" }); 
        }     
    );
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't use CSS directly for this. Use classes:

```
a.bold { font-weight: bold; }
```

with:

```
$("ul.tabs > li> a").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("ul.tabs").children("li").children("a.bold")
    .removeClass("bold").end().addClass("bold");
  return false;    
});
```

Direct CSS changes are *destructive*. You can't roll them back. Classes on the other hand can be freely added and removed in a non-destructive manner and lead to better solutions (assuming the CSS property values aren't dynamic).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do this ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs li a").click(
        function() { 
           $(".tabs li a").css({ "font-weight" : "normal" });
           $(this).css({ "font-weight" : "bold" }); }     

    );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although all the above suggestion will work, my recommended solution is much simpler. JavaScript is behavioural so it should be just used for that. So I would suggest adding a class to the parent *li* when the *a* is clicked. You should just toggle a class:

JS

```
​$('.tabs li a').click(function()​​​​​ {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('bold');
    return false;
});​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS

```
.bold a {
    font-weight: bold; 
}​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XWdVe/